# Angular-Oboe + NodeJS stream error non-whitespace character before

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, stream, stdout

NodeJS server:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

app.get('/ls', function(req, res) {
  exec('ls',
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
      res.send(stdout);
  });
});
```

Angular Client (standard implementation from the example on [its GitHubPage](https://github.com/RonB/angular-oboe)):

```
$scope.myData = [];


Oboe({
        url: $scope.baseUrl + ":" + $scope.port + "/ls",
        pattern: '*',
        start: function(stream) {
            // handle to the stream
            $scope.stream = stream;
            $scope.streamStatus = 'started';
        },
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Basic '  + $rootScope.globals.currentUser['authdata']
        },
        done: function() {
            $scope.streamStatus = 'done';
        }
    }).then(function() {
        // finished loading
    }, function(error) {
      console.log(error);
        // handle errors
    }, function(node) {
        // node received
        console.log(node);
        $scope.myData.push(node);
    });
```

When I check the request, I get the following successful response:

```
data
index.js
license
node_modules
npm-debug.log
package.json
readme.md
routes
test.js
```

But Oboe doesn't seem to want to process this. Here's the error I'm getting client-side:

```
Object {statusCode: undefined, body: undefined, jsonBody: undefined, thrown: Error: Non-whitespace before {[.
Ln: 1
Col: 1
Chr: d
    at Error (native)
    at c (http://www.samh…}body: undefinedjsonBody: undefinedstatusCode: undefinedthrown: Error: Non-whitespace before {[.
Ln: 1
Col: 1
Chr: d
    at Error (native)
    at c (http://localhost:8080/vendor/oboe/dist/oboe-browser.min.js:1:1633)
    at h (http://localhost:8080/vendor/oboe/dist/oboe-browser.min.js:1:2054)
    at z (http://localhost:8080/vendor/oboe/dist/oboe-browser.min.js:1:1233)
    at a.emit (http://localhost:8080/vendor/oboe/dist/oboe-browser.min.js:1:7560)
    at XMLHttpRequest.j (http://localhost:8080/vendor/oboe/dist/oboe-browser.min.js:1:6314)__proto__: Object
```

I've also tried JSON.stringify()-ing the stdout to no avail. Why would I be getting this error? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried with `res.status(200).json(stdout)`?

Comment: Thanks! It's still throwing the same error, though.

Comment: Seems like Oboe isn't recieving any response at all looking at the error. What if you change the `url` property in the Oboe config object to this: `url: '/ls'` because it'll default to current `<protocol>://<host>:<port>`.

Comment: In the browser's network inspector, I'm seeing a 200 OK response with all the data, though. So I think the call is being made correctly to the right URL by Oboe.

Comment: Could you create a paste of the data returned by the server? Just to make sure that it is in fact valid JSON. You can also try to wrap your response in an object like so: `res.status(200).json({ data: stdout })`

Comment: @SamuelHill res.send(stdout); does not send json data so no suprise it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Please send an object in the response

example: `res.status('yourstatuscode').send(passanobjecthere);`

```
res.status(401).send({
message: 'Server error'
})
```